# How can I make the sidebar more narrow?

Tags: 8, theming

I am trying to make the sidebar more narrow in a Bootstrap 3 theme, in Drupal 8. There is no numbered class like col-sm-4 here that I could change. What is the right approach to take in this case?

```
<div class="row">
  {% if page.sidebar_first %}
    <aside class="{{sidebar_grid_class}}">  
      <!--#sidebar-first-->
      <section id="sidebar-first" class="sidebar clearfix">
        {{ page.sidebar_first }}
      </section>
    </aside>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

col-sm-4 will be applied via a function in the theme. if you search through the theme for where the variable is set you can change it there. Possibly in the .theme file.